# Modify target of unpinned applications in taskbar

Tags: taskbar, shortcuts, path

Example: 
I do not have MS Excel is not pinned. When opened, its icon shows up in taskbar. To open a new instance, that taskbar icon can be middle clicked. But to open it without loading a blank workbook, an /e switch is needed in the icon's target box (see [Opening New Blank Instance of Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1022357/stop-opening-new-workbook-when-starting-excel/1022393?noredirect=1#comment1424006_1022393)). 
I think I found the path with the shortcuts (see [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/58561/where-are-the-shortcuts-for-the-windows-7-taskbar-stored-on-disk), but because it's not pinned, I found it in the "StartMenu" folder instead of "TaskBar". I'm hoping it's the same shortcut as the one appearing on the taskbar).
However, going into its properties, the "Target" path is greyed out.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 7. (But i'm sure users of other Windows versions could appreciate an answer for them as well...?)

Comment: Delete the existing Excel shortcut from the Start Menu, then replace with a new shortcut that you create with a target of `"<your-path>\excel.exe" /e`.